# Reduce the effect of excessive zeros

Tags: deep-learning, autoregressive, lstm, zero-inflation

I am working on an autoregression problem where I use sequential LSTM. My target is well defined, but I think I am facing a problem with the features. As the features were non-stationary, then I decided to apply the log-returns to each of them. In other words, if $F_t$ is a feature at a certain time $t$, then I apply $$\log(\frac{F_t}{F_{t-1}}).$$

$\Rightarrow$ [Why non-stationary data is hard to analyse?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8875/why-non-stationary-data-cannot-be-analyzed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The property makes it easier to analyse, but produce a lot of zeros when $F_t = F_{t-1}$.

As there is lots of zeros, then the predictions tend to be closer to 0. How can I reduce that effect mathematically?

Comment: You've added the [tag:zero-inflation] tag to your post, so presumably you know about zero-inflated regressions. If you can write the MLE of the ZIP/ZINB regression, then you can minimize the negative MLE using SGD, *even if you're estimating a neural network.* Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am not that familiar with zero-inflated regression, but I know what it is. Are you up to build a full answer to explain to me how formally I can use neural network and zero-inflated regression to reduce the impact of excessive zeros?